# Where's my syntax error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax

```
SyntaxError in Videos#show

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/videos/show.html.erb where line #54 raised:

compile error
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:272: syntax error, unexpected ')'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:273: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting $end
Extracted source (around line #54):

51:         <%= link_to "Show Song", '#', :id => 'video_show_link', :class => 'edit' %>
52:     
53:         <div id="showable_video_div">
54:             <%= form_for [@video, @video.showable_videos.new ], :url => showable_videos_path, :remote => true do |f| %>
55:                 <%= f.hidden_field :video_id, :value => @video.id, :id => "video_id_field" %>
56:                 <%= f.text_field :user, :class => "showable_field" %>
57:             <% end %>
```

This is the migration to the `showable_videos` table that I did right before the error was thrown:

```
class AddUpvotedAndSeenToShowableVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :showable_videos, :upvoted?, :boolean
    add_column :showable_videos, :seen?, :boolean
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :showable_videos, :seen?
   remove_column :showable_videos, :upvoted?
  end
end
```

Comment: What's `[@video, @video.showable_videos.new]` supposed to yield?

Comment: The syntax error is in your title. Wheres ==> Where's

Comment: in the video model: `has_many :showable_videos`

Comment: @user730569 theIV got it. You didn't get it.

Comment: actually this migration may have something to do with this error ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just undid the migration above and then ran the migration again without the `?` in the column names. I no longer get the syntax error.

Comment: Indeed that would fixed it, Rails automatically provides those methods so if you add it yourself on that column it won't work.

Comment: You should accept your answer ;) You may also report a bug in Rails (I guess it may also be a bug in the documentation). Rails should return an error saying that question marks are not legal in Rails table column names. PostgreSQL, for example, allows you to create such columns. Since Rails define reader methods with question marks ("name?" for attribute "name") using this character in the base column may be questionable.